# How to get a distinct value of a row with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have table with value

```
id country 
1  india
2  usa
3  india
```

I need to find the distinct values from the country column using sequelize.js

here my sample code...

```
Project.findAll({

    attributes: ['country'],
    distinct: true
}).then(function(country) {
     ...............
});
```

Is there any way to find the distict values

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try with this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2996#issuecomment-141424712

```
Project.aggregate('country', 'DISTINCT', { plain: false })
.then(...)
```

Comment: how do you alias the 'DISTINCT' column name? It returns a table in which the column name is 'DISTINCT'

Comment: how can you make sure it's distinct but also latest (via createdAt)

Answer (score 85):

You can specify distinct for one or more attributes using `Sequelize.fn`

```
Project.findAll({
    attributes: [
        // specify an array where the first element is the SQL function and the second is the alias
        [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('country')) ,'country'],

        // specify any additional columns, e.g. country_code
        // 'country_code'

    ]
}).then(function(country) {  })
```

Comment: SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: did you find out the correct syntax?

Comment: I ended up writing sql query, which was much easier and also did manual work in js

Comment: using MySQL, this solution works - make sure to use the DISTINCT field as the first attribute.

Comment: @Endel how ? because sequelize always override the position of the distinct column

Comment: this works fine for postgres. @MuhammadUmer, which database did you use ?

Comment: The above syntax works provided you are not including another model, on adding include it throws `SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"`

Comment: The issue for me was that _Sequelize_ wanted to prefix the columns list with the primary key of the model, which causes `SELECT id, DISTINCT col1, col2` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2`. No matter what I tried, it never worked, and the problem was always that one. Eventually, the solution was cryptic and easy enough: I just needed to add `raw: true` to the options of `findAll`. BTW, here is the documentation of that option: "If true, sequelize will not try to format the results of the query, or build an instance of a model from the result". Now, tell me if that's not even more cryptic!

Answer (score 35):

I ended up using grouping like this:

```
Project.findAll({
  attributes: ['country'],
  group: ['country']
}).then(projects => 
  projects.map(project => project.country)
);
```

It results into distinct models you can nicely iterate.

*Link in previous answer helped little bit: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2996#issuecomment-141424712*

This works well too, but generating response with DISTINCT as column name:

```
Project.aggregate('country', 'DISTINCT', { plain: false })
  .then(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the the `group` option, however to avoid the MySQL error `incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` you must apply the `MAX` function to others attributes.

```js
const countries = await Project.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn("MAX", Sequelize.col("id")), "id"],
    "country",
  ],
  group: ["country"],
});
```

which should generate a sql query like the following:

```sql
SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id`, `country` FROM `project` GROUP BY `country`;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone -

The accepted answer:

```
Project.findAll({
    attributes: [
        // specify an array where the first element is the SQL function and the second is the alias
        [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('country')) ,'country'],

        // specify any additional columns, e.g. country_code
        // 'country_code'

    ]
}).then(function(country) {  })
```

errored out for me with an error message of "attr[0].indexOf is not a function". My sequelize version is: 4.13.8

I found that this gave me distinct records:

```
const query = {
  attributes: [ ['DISTINCT (label)','label'], 'fieldId'],
  raw: true 
};
const labelsAndFields = (await TableModel.findAll(query));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw queries to get the result or `sequelize.fn()`.

[Here’s the documentation on Sequelize raw queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the below code to get the required output:

```
Project.findAll({
  attributes: ['country'],
  distinct: true,
  col: '__Column name you want to distinct with__'
}).then(function(country) {
     ...............
});
```

I found this solution after a long time of searching and debugging. It also works with the INCLUDE clause. For example:

```
Project.findAll({
  where: {....}
  attributes: ['country'],
  include: [.....],
  distinct: true,
  col: '__Column name you want to distinct with__'
}).then(function(country) {
...............
});
```