# How to get Distinct records from SQL db using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I need latest updated whole row after applying sql logic.

My Table,

```
uid       name   device_id    date
-----------------------------------------
abc-123   abc    d-1          2022-06-14
abc-123   abc    d-2          2022-06-13
qwe-365   qwe    d-1          2022-06-18
abc-123   abc    d-1          2022-06-19
abc-123   abc    d-1          2022-06-21
```

I need the answer like, where device_id & uid together need to be unique & row having the latest date needs to be filtered.

```
uid       name   device_id    date
-----------------------------------
abc-123   abc    d-1          2022-06-21
abc-123   abc    d-2          2022-06-13
qwe-365   qwe    d-1          2022-06-18



let userIds=['abc-123']
```

Method-1:

```
UserSession.findAll({
where:{
    uid:{[Op.in]: userIds}
},
attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('uid')), 'uid']
    ,'date', 'device_id'                
], raw: true
}).then((sessions, err)=>{
if(err) reject(err)
console.log("DB Response : ", sessions)
})
```

Result: "By running this query, it's not giving distinct values showing all records".

Method-2:

```
UserSession.findAll({
    where:{
        uid:{[Op.in]: userIds}
    },
    attributes:['uid'],
    group:['uid'],
    raw:true
  }).then(projects =>                     
    projects.map(project => {
        console.log(project)
        console.log("UID: >", project.uid)
    })
  );
```

Result: "It's giving only unique uid values in the table, not entire row"

Method-3

```
UserSession.findAll({
    where:{
        uid:{[Op.in]: userIds}
    },
    attributes:['uid', 'date', 'device_id'],
    group:['uid'],
    raw:true
  }).then(projects =>                     
    projects.map(project => {
        console.log(project)
        console.log("UID: >", project.uid)
    })
  );
```

Error Message:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]
at Query.formatError (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:244:16)
at Query.handler [as onResult] (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:51:23)
at Query.execute (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:30:14)
at Connection.handlePacket (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
parent: Error
  at Packet.asError (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
  at Query.execute (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
  at Connection.handlePacket (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
  at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
  at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
  at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
  at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
code: 'ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP',
errno: 1055,
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: '',
sql: "SELECT `uid`, `date`, `device_id` FROM `UserSessions` AS `UserSessions` WHERE `UserSessions`.`uid` IN ('abc-123') GROUP BY `uid`;",
parameters: undefined
},
original: Error
  at Packet.asError (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
  at Query.execute (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
  at Connection.handlePacket (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
  at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
  at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dev/Desktop/WORK/Service/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
  at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
  at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
code: 'ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP',
errno: 1055,
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: '',
sql: "SELECT `uid`, `date`, `device_id` FROM `UserSessions` AS `UserSessions` WHERE `UserSessions`.`uid` IN ('abc-123') GROUP BY `uid`;",
parameters: undefined
},
sql: "SELECT `uid`, `date`, `device_id` FROM `UserSessions` AS `UserSessions` WHERE `UserSessions`.`uid` IN ('abc-123') GROUP BY `uid`;",
parameters: undefined
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a distinct value of a row with sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519695/how-to-get-a-distinct-value-of-a-row-with-sequelize)

Comment: No, I tried in that method. It's only giving specific column unique value. If I'm adding more attribute values it's giving error

Comment: Please, using [edit], add the code that you tried, and the complete error message.

Comment: Please add `,catch(err => console.log(err))`  as a chain to `.then` to see the actual error

Comment: Updated can you please check.. now?